# AJAX: CSS style application to a row

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I need a help with the following code. There are 2 styles: `activatedRow` and `disactivatedRow`. When a user clicks on a button (located inside the TD of a table), then either `activatedRow` or `disactivatedRow` is applied to a row. Selection of a style is based on current style. For instance, if a row is activated, then the button will disactivate it, and vice versa.

So, I have a problem with `AJAX success`. How to write IF statement to check current style of a row?

P.S. Also it would be interesting to know how to change TD IMG (button) for disactivated and activated rows.

**CSS**

```
.activatedRow td { 
    background-color:#FFFFFF !important;
    color: #000000 !important;
}
.disactivatedRow td { 
    background-color:#DFE1ED !important;
    color: #9896A8 !important;
}
```

**Function "disactivateRow()"**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function disactivateRow(flightNum,obj){ 
           $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "callpage.php?page=tables/disactivate.php",
                   data: "flightNum=" + flightNum,
                   success: function(){
                       if ($(obj).hasClass("activatedRow")) {
                    $(obj).removeClass("activatedRow").addClass("disactivatedRow");
                } else
                    $(obj).removeClass("disactivatedRow").addClass("activatedRow");
               }
            });
}
</script>
```

**Button inside the table**

```
            <table id="newspaper-b" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width = "100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Flt Num</th>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($result1 as $row):
                        $flightNum=$row['flightNum'];
                    ?>
                    <tr id="<?php echo $flightNum; ?>" class="edit_tr">
                        <td><?php echo $flightNum;?></td>
                        <td id="<?php echo $flightNum; ?>">
                             <div onclick='disactivateRow("<?php echo $flightNum; ?>", this)'>
                                <img src='images/disactivate.png' alt='Disactivate' />
                            </div>              
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**jQuery DataTable activation**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#newspaper-b').dataTable({
      "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
      "bJQueryUI":true,
      'fnRowCallback': function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {     
          if (aData[0] == "0") {
                    nRow.className = "disactivatedRow";
              } else
                    nRow.className = "activatedRow"; 
            return nRow;
        }

      });
```

**ANSWER:**

It works now:

```
      $(".disact_but" ).click(function() {
            var ID=$(this).attr('id');
                $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "callpage.php?page=tables/disactivate.php",
                       data: "flightNum=" + ID,
                       success: function(){
                            $("#"+ID).toggleClass("disactivatedRow", 100);
                       }
                });
            return false;
      });
```

Comment: P.S. It's "deactivate", not "disactivate".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `obj` is the TD to apply the style as your code indicates you could use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

> Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the switch argument.

```
$(obj).closest('tr').toggleClass('disactivatedRow');
$(obj).closest('tr').toggleClass('activatedRow');
```

**EDIT**

According new information you added, `obj` is a row's child. `closest` method should give you the appropiate `tr` and then we can apply `toggleClass`

Comment: Please look at the update. jQuery DataTable is created in such a way that activatedRow and disactivatedRow styles are applied to each row. It works fine. But when I click on the button 'disactivateRow', nothing happens. I need to reload the page to see the result.

Comment: And I tried your code. In fact nothing has changed. Maybe you could take a look at the update and post more detailed answer? Thanks.